# Send email with a table in the body without attachment

Tags: python, html, email, html-email

I am trying to send an email without attachement from a csv file. This csv file is a 3*9 cells +1 header row.

I want to send in this format in a nice format.

This is my code:

```
me = 'email'
        password = 'password'
        server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
        you = 'email'       
        text = """
        Hello, Friend.

        Here is your data:

        {0}

        Regards,

        Me"""

        html = """
        <html><body><p>Hello, Friend.</p>
            <p>Here is your data:</p>
        {0}
            <p>Regards,</p>
        <p>Me</p>
        </body></html>
        """

        with open('test.csv','r') as fin:
            reader=csv.reader(fin, delimiter=',')
                all_text = str()
        for row in reader:
                    temp=list(row)
                    all_text+= '\n'.join(row) 

            text = text.format(all_text, tablefmt="grid")
        html = html.format(all_text,  tablefmt="html")

        message = MIMEMultipart(
            "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

        message['Subject'] = "Your data"
        message['From'] = me
        message['To'] = you
            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(me, password)
        server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
        server.quit()
```

It is working, but in the email there isn't any seperator, there isn't any cells, it looks very bad and unreadable.

How can i fix the format?

Comment: Try using tabulate() function. This is a link to a similar answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930239/printing-mutiple-html-tables-using-tabulate-in-python

Comment: `str.format` doesn't accept the keyword `tablefmt` that looks like a keyword for [tabulate](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate)

Comment: I tried with tabulate, but it isn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing mutiple HTML tables using tabulate in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930239/printing-mutiple-html-tables-using-tabulate-in-python)

Comment: Code it as tables with inline CSS.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question** from a csv file. - with a table in the body - in a nice format

Example using `pandas` to get both `text` and `html` table.

- [pandas.DataFrame.to_string](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html?highlight=to_string#pandas.DataFrame.to_string)
- [pandas.DataFrame.to_html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html?highlight=to_html#pandas.DataFrame.to_html)

---

- `CSV` Data

  ```
  CSV = """Ville,Aire_urbaine,Pôle_urbain,Commune
  Paris,12.568.755,10.733.971,2.190.327
  Lyon,2.310.850,1.651.365,515.695
  Saint-Étienne,519.834,374.175,171.924
  """
  ```
- Read `CSV` Data to `pd.Dataframe`

  ```
  df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(CSV), sep=',')
  ```
- Format `txt`

  ```
  text = str(df)
  #text = df.to_string(index=False)
  ```

  > **Output**:
  >
  > ```
  >            Ville Aire_urbaine Pôle_urbain    Commune
  > 0          Paris   12.568.755  10.733.971  2.190.327
  > 1           Lyon    2.310.850   1.651.365    515.695
  > 2  Saint-Étienne      519.834     374.175    171.924
  > ```
- Format `html`

  ```
  html = df.to_html()
  ```

  > **Output**:
  >
  > ```
  > <table border="1" class="dataframe">
  >   <thead>
  >     <tr style="text-align: right;">
  >       <th></th>
  >       <th>Ville</th>
  >       <th>Aire_urbaine</th>
  >       <th>Pôle_urbain</th>
  >       <th>Commune</th>
  >     </tr>
  >   </thead>
  >   <tbody>
  >     <tr>
  >       <th>0</th>
  >       <td>Paris</td>
  >       <td>12.568.755</td>
  >       <td>10.733.971</td>
  >       <td>2.190.327</td>
  >     </tr>
  >     ... (omitted for brevity)
  >   </tbody>
  > </table>
  > ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: @Mr.D: *"With python 2.7 is itsn't working"*: You didn't tag your Question with `python-2.7`. Did you consider to upgrade? Are at least the output what you want?